# Editing after saving doesn't save select option

Tags: laravel, select, laravel-backpack

After saving the form, once I go back to edit, my select option filed is not saved. 
I have two models PDA_Kategorije and PDA_Potkategorije.

```
class PDAPotkategorije extends Model
```

{
    use CrudTrait;

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| GLOBAL VARIABLES
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

protected $table = 'pda_potkategorije';
// protected $primaryKey = 'id';
// public $timestamps = false;
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $fillable = ['name', 'pdakategorija_id'];
// protected $hidden = [];
// protected $dates = [];



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FUNCTIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

public function pda_kategorije()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PDAKategorije', 'id', 'pdakategorija_id');
}
```

class PDAKategorije extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| GLOBAL VARIABLES
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

protected $table = 'pda_kategorije';
// protected $primaryKey = 'id';
// public $timestamps = false;
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $fillable = ['name'];
// protected $hidden = [];
// protected $dates = [];

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FUNCTIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

public function pda_potkategorije()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PDAPotkategorije', 'pdakategorija_id', 'id');
}
```

In PDAPotkategorijeCrudController i have

```
        $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'name',
        'type' => 'text',
    ]);

    $this->crud->addField([
        'label' => "Odaberite kategoriju",
        'type' => 'select',
        'name' => 'pdakategorija_id', // the relationship name in your Model
        'entity' => 'pda_kategorije', // the relationship name in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // attribute on Article that is shown to admin
        'model' => "App\Models\PDAKategorije", //
    ]);
```

In setupListOperation, pda_potkategorije is properly assigned to pda_kategorije
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCcez.jpg

But once i click on edit pda_kategorije select option is not saved.